# Nicescroll : I am using jquery nicescroll but in mobile version i still can see the original scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, nicescroll

I have integrated **Nicescroll** in my project but I still can see the original scrollbar under the new one.

the very first thing i tried is `overflow : hidden;` on my body tag but it didn't work

this CSS lines fixed it for the desktop version but nothing worked so far for the mobile version .

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none !important;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
body {
  -webkit-appearance: none ;
  -ms-overflow-style: none !important;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none !important;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Comment: is there any breakpoints in your css? (@media tags)

Comment: yeah and  i've added it there too

Comment: It is a not updated 110kb dependency that will not function before it is fully loaded.. last update was 3 years ago. So maybe try http://grsmto.github.io/simplebar/ that is only 10kB or use `overflow-y` and use modern css to get the same result without a plugin?